# Plot line between 2 points in Julia

Tags: julia, plots.jl, julia-plots

Suppose we have drawn 10 points and we want to draw a simple line between each one of them.

```
begin
    x,y = rand(1:10, 10), rand(1:10, 10)
    scatter(x,y)
    #Some drawing line code
end
```

How can we do this in Julia using Plots.jl package?, I'd been searching for a while but haven't found anything useful yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the function `plot` with the keyword `marker`:

```
using Plots
x,y = rand(1:10, 10), rand(1:10, 10)
plot(x, y; marker=(:circle,5))
```

result:

[image: plot]